# Sql LEFT OUTER JOIN with WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

**Request:**

```
 RequestID | Msg
----------------
    5  | abc
    6  | def
    7  | ghi
    8  | jkl
```

**RequestStatus:**

```
RequestStatusID | RequestID |StatusID
-------------------------------------
        1             5         1
        2             8         2
```

- Not every request has a record in `RequestStatus`

I need all the records from table `Request` except when `StatusID = 2`.  (`requestID=8` should be filter-out)

I am using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to recieve the records from table `Request` but when I am adding Where clause `(Where StatusID = 1)` of course it does not work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Move the constraint to your on clause.

```
select *
from request r
left join requestStatus rs
on r.requestID = rs.requestID
--and status_id = 1
and status_id <> 2
```

What's happening to you is that the outer join is performed first.  Any rows coming from the outer join that don't have matches will have nulls in all the columns.  Then your where clause is applied, but since 1 <> null, it's not going to work like you want it to.

EDIT: Changed on clause based on Piyush's comment.

Comment: I think OP wants all rows except where statusID = 2 , not only 1

Comment: That won't filter out rows where `StatusID = 2`. Only remove the right side.

Comment: This worked great for me on another example. Great idea

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server 2017 you can put AND after ON in this way

```
SELECT * FROM Request
LEFT OUTER JOIN RequestStatus ON Request.RequestID = RequestStatus.RequestID
AND RequestStatus.StatusID <> 2
WHERE Request.RequestID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM Request R
  LEFT JOIN RequestStatus RS ON R.RequestID  =  RS.RequestID   
  WHERE RS.StatusID <> 2 OR RS.RequestID IS NULL
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e82fe/9)

Answer (score 1):

You need use an NOT IN Query Statement like this

```
Select * 
From Request 
Where RequestID not in 
    (Select RequestID 
    From RequestStatus 
    Where StatusID = 2)
```

or

```
Select * 
From Request r 
left join requestStatus rs on r.requestID = rs.requestID 
Where r.RequestID not in 
    (Select RequestID 
    From RequestStatus 
    Where StatusID = 2)
```

Comment: Andrew's Answer is cleaner than mine

Comment: Using the not exists clause is faster than Except, Not In, Outer Apply, etc in this article by [Aaron Bertrand - Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple, use left join but filter on the rows that have StatusId different than 2, like so:

```
select *
from request r
left join requestStatus rs
on r.requestID = rs.requestID
where rs.StatusId <> 2 or rs.StatusId IS NULL
```

EDIT: added or rs.StatusId IS NULL additional condition to also include rows in requestStatus table that don't have a match in request table.

Comment: @Andrew, "I need all the records from table Request except when StatusID = 2. (requestID=8 should be filter-out)".. what else does it need to be said?

Comment: That would be why I deleted my boneheaded comment :)

Comment: However, this solution still breaks the outer join:  [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8efa/5)

Comment: Not mine but putting the outer table in the where clause enforces that only non-NULL rows will be included and checked against that filter. Effectively, this turns your outer join into an inner join, and no longer returns the rows the OP wants.

Comment: @Andrew, thank you for the comment and fiddle, it made me reconsider the where clause. Just edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1b49/1)

This answer assumes you just want the RequestId & Msg from the Request Table where there is not a record in the RequestStatus table with that RequestId and a StatusId of 2.

You won't get extra records for Requests with multiple RequestStatus records using this query either (vs Left join).

Using the **not exists** clause is faster than Except, Not In, Outer Apply, etc in this article by [Aaron Bertrand - Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

```sql
select r.RequestId, r.Msg
  from Request r
  where not exists (
    select 1 
    from RequestStatus rs 
    where rs.StatusId = 2
      and rs.RequestId = r.RequestId
    )
```