# Filter active records using Outer join

Tags: mysql

I have a simple membership system which allows user to upload multiple avatars so they can set an active one to be displayed.
I also want to display an avatar by default if they don't choose a custom avatar.
I'm trying to display it at once using MySQL, here is a small snippet of what my tables looks like :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `custom_avatar` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `avatars` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `avatar_file` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

What I got so far using joins :

```
SELECT members.id, members.name, avatars.avatar_file
FROM members
LEFT OUTER JOIN avatars
ON members.id = avatars.user_id
```

I guess I'm not that far away of the solution, I just have to check if the user has no custom avatars ( ie: if the record is NULL ) then display the default one.
The main problem here is I'm unable to get the active avatars only, as far as I know I can't put a WHERE clause on it, that will negates what I'm trying to achieve so far.

Any enlightements to do that in a single request using MySql or shall I dig further in PHP ?

**EDIT :**

Expected output : to display active avatars only if there are any, NULL if not.

The query I've posted above is in fact displaying every single avatars a user may have, here is an example of the output I got :

### ** name avatar_file**

- Admin    avatar_admin_03-19-59.jpg
- Admin    avatar_admin_19-33-29.jpg
- John     NULL
- Member1 NULL

( I'm sorry I don't know how to render the results properly )

If I use anything like *where active = 1* it does filter any NULL records which I need to figure out if a user has a custom avatar or not.

Comment: Give some sample data and expected output based on that data.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - you're one third of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations I came across this solution which works like a charm :

[Sql LEFT OUTER JOIN with WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607144/sql-left-outer-join-with-where-clause)

Of course as Ulla-Brendholdt advised I could also check for nulls, my bad here.

Answer (score -1):

you should check for nulls :

```
Active = 1 or avatars.user_id IS NULL
```